# Is in Admob VPN is Haram or Halal?

Tags: halal-haram

Iam using VPN to click on Ads to get high earning.Is it haram or halal?
I am not use VPN to unblock sites which are blocked by our government but I just change my country location to other countries to get high earning on clicking on Ads is it halal earning in Islam?

Answer (score 1):

Its Simple: 
If Admob rate is low in your country but you are trying to get high earning by changing your country location then Yes You are doing **WRONG** because you can make people/company fool but not **Allah**. Earn low but make sure its Halal. Your Halal earning will be double, no matter if its low because Its Barkah in Halal earning.